# Java Mysql table data output formatting

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

Here is my MySql table:

[image: mysql table]

I want to show the output of the query in commandline as below:

[image]

I have written the code below to loop but I am getting only the first row, What i have to modify ??

```
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(table_retrive);
                String[] cols = new String[itemList.size()];
                int[] rec =new int[itemList.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {

                     while (rs2.next()) {
                        cols[i] =(String) itemList.get(i);
                        rec[i] = rs2.getInt(cols[i]);
                        System.out.println(rec[i]+" ");
                       }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of the inner loop is your problem.

You can enhance your code to remove the usage of the second loop in your code, it basically does nothing. You can loop over your result set and in the same loop using the incremented variable to persist the values accordingly.

The code shown half implemented in your question, hence it will be difficult to give you exactly what need to be done. Nevertheless, here's an attempt to resolve the problem for you:

```
while (rs2.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs2.getInt(1) + "\t |" + rs2.getString(2) + "\t |" + rs2.getString(3));
}
```

> Based on the column names from the table in the question, assuming that column2 and column3 are `String`'s.

You can add the necessary details to this code to complete it according to your usecase, but I've just taken the example of showing a record in one line.

**EDIT:**

OP has his own way of programming, but to satisfy his question in the comment - this is how you can do it.

```
while (rs2.next()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) 
    { 
        cols[i] =(String) itemList.get(i); 
        rec[i] = rs2.getInt(cols[i]); 
        System.out.print(rec[i]+"\t |"); 
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use printf() Or format() method. It is same as printf method in c lang. you can pass parameters and difference. Look at [link1](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/displaying-text-using-printf-method)
And [link 2](https://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/introduction.htm)

```
Example : System.out.printf("%d%5s%10d", 5,"|",10);
output : 5    |        10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two loops are wrong. Start at `i=0` and then iterate once over the whole `ResultSet`, filling yor first array position. When this is done, `i` is incremented and you try to iterate the `ResultSet` a second time but the cursor is at the end of the `ResultSet`, so `rs2.next()` returns `false` and the code will not be executed.

So you have two Solutions:

1. Handle the loops correctly. Unfortunately I do not know, what you are trying to do anyways because this is some C-like code without OOP, which doesn't show semantics and then you have this `itemList` which seems to hold preset values and you read out of this list, which column to take for the `i`-th position. This seems odd. Maybe switching the loops does the desired: Start with the `while` and nest the `for`.
2. Reset the cursor of the `ResultSet` after the `while` with `rs2.beforeFirst()`. WARNING: This could throw a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`. Not all Databases can move the cursor backwards. This is of course a very ugly solution, since you should first parse the whole row a once.

Answer (score 0):

Using this the I got all the values but in one row :

```
               while (rs2.next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {

                        cols[i] =(String) itemList.get(i);
                        rec[i] = rs2.getInt(cols[i]);
                        System.out.print(rec[i]+" ");
                              }
                        }
```

But I need to divide like the rows.